# In a CloudFormation template, how can I use the output of a command of a deployed EC2 instance as a stack output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

In a CloudFormation template, I create an EC2 instance, and I want to securely get some data from the instance itself and use it in a stack output variable. How can I do that?

In particular, I want to save the SSH host keys that are autogenerated at deployment time as a stack output variable, so that I can easily verify them if I need to connect over SSH during troubleshooting.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, but an alternative solution would be to use a known host key. https://alestic.com/2012/04/ec2-ssh-host-key/ talks a little about this issue. Their solution is much better than blind trust, but still not quite perfect...

Comment: write down your current attempt/ template, we will help you if possible.

Comment: Hmm, uploading the SSH host key is an interesting idea. I may attempt that  if I have to, but I would prefer to generate it securely on the EC2 instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know what you intend to do with the stack export, however you have a couple of options. One very good one is mentioned by Matt in the comments of your question (it should be posted as an answer). That would allow you to pass the key in as a parameter to your stack and then export it directly.

One other option, depending on your use case, is to have your instance save its host key to S3 in a secure bucket during the processing of its user data. From there you can retrieve it later. This approach comes with an element of risk, that you could inadvertently make your key available to others by changing the security on your bucket. To work around this, you could encrypt your key using KMS first using the AWS CLI, and then decrypt it when you go to use it elsewhere.

Both of these options feel uncomfortable, but perhaps if you explain your use case there might be another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hmm, generating it on the instance and then having the instance save it to S3 is an interesting idea. I would only have to save the public key, which wouldn't pose a security risk. An interesting idea. Regarding my use case, what kind of information do you need from me about it? In general, I want to be able to deploy an EC2 instance and immediately connect to it securely, without risking MITM or leaking the SSH host keys. Is that the kind of information you need, or do you need more specifics?